# Sound menu disappeared

Tags: unity, 11.10, indicator-sound

The sound menu have disappeared in 11.10 have anyone had a same problem ?

Comment: On ubuntu 10.04 happens the same to me. if you clicked on the speaker icon -> "Sound settings..." it lead you to a system-settings windows where a lot of icons where missing, even sound. Reinstalling ubuntu desktop as recommends Swizzla did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, same problem here. More generally, the old System Settings icon is missing in 11.10. To access your settings (and change speaker volume):

1. Right-click your username in the upper-right corner of your screen, on the toolbar.
2. If you do not see "System Settings" on the menu, try right-clicking directly to the right of your username on the toolbar.
3. Select "System Settings". Right-click on "Sound" and change your sound settings as needed.

There is an "Other" tab with more settings--I'm posting the link to a blog with more information about how to access this tab. You will need to 'un-hide' it under "Edit Menus" in order to use it:

http://ubuntugenius.wordpress.com/2011/10/17/ubuntu-11-10-upgrade-missing-your-system-menu-preferences-administration-launchers/

Comment: The've just released an update and it seems the problem has been fix. Ubuntu has an awesome team. I've been using alsamixer to control the sound before and it worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Re-installing `libindicator-sound` `ubuntu-desktop`, and the pulseaudio x11 plugin fixed this for me. My sound menu disappeared from the unity panel when there was some kind of conflict, and they were accidentally removed.